# Replacing strings with values from an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a requirement to edit all files within a folder with 2000 subfolders. The files and the folders that they reside in share the common quality of having the computer name listed. The files listed have the exact same variables within them that need to get changed.

I am attempting to use an excel spreadsheet that has 3 columns; computer name, IP address, and MAC address. I am attempting to use this spreadsheet to find and replace the variables based upon the computer name.

For example, if the script finds folder computer1 with files computer1.txt computer1.abc, it will then find the variables within it and replace them with the computer name, IP address, and MAC address listed within the spreadsheet that correspond with the computer name.

So far I have managed to create a script to find the variables needed within the files and replace them.

```
  get-childItem -path "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Test\Computers\*\*.*" -recurse | % `
{
$filepath = $_.FullName;
(get-content -path "$filepath") -replace '<HOST_NAME></HOST_NAME>', '<HOST_NAME>TEST</HOST_NAME>'  | set-content $filepath -Force
}
```

As you can see, the above changes everything to the same value, if I do a section for each computer, that's a lot of manual typing.

I am assuming an array would be used but I am unsure on how to incorporate this into my current script. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could compare the folder name to the computer name in your spreadsheet to get the information. Then you can insert that information into your `-replace` operations.

```
$CSV = Import-CSV "C:\PathToYourSpreadsheet.csv"   
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Test\Computers\" -Directory -Recurse 
Foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    If ($CSV.ComputerName -contains $Folder.Basename) {
        $ComputerInfo = $CSV | Where-Object {$_.ComputerName -eq $Folder.Basename}
        $File = Get-ChildItem $Folder.Fullname -File -Include *.abc
        #If multiple files, add another loop here
        (Get-Content -Path $File.Fullname) -Replace '<HOST_NAME></HOST_NAME>', "<HOST_NAME>$($ComputerInfo.ComputerName)</HOST_NAME>"  | Set-Content $File.Fullname -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: BenH, Thanks for the code! I tried it out when I made changes to the extension of file that I would be working with but nothing changed. I used two folders as a test environment but none of the variables were changed. I will continue to look into this! Thank's again though!